# Access validator messages in controller Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to access the messages from the validator in the controller using the following code.

```
    $valid = Validator::make($input,$rules);
    print_r($valid->messages());
```

However, I'm not getting any output even though the validation is `failing`.

What do I need to do to get the Laravel-generated validation messages?

Comment: Strange. try this $failed = $valid->failed(); dd($failed);

Comment: It should work. If you get no output are you sure that your to your controller route is proper configuring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run $validator->fails() or $validator->passes() before checking for the messages:

```
$valid = Validator::make($input,$rules);
$validator->fails();
print_r($valid->messages());
```

But assuming you know that, well, you could be using `messages()->all()`, but the way you're are doing should work. Try this (standalone-ish) code in your end:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'Dayle'),
    array('name' => 'required|min:15')
);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    // The given data did not pass validation
}

print_r($validator->messages()->all());
```

If it works then the problem is realated to your `$input` and/or `$rules`.

Comment: That works. The issue was I wasn't running the _fails()_ method first!